# Conversion unsuccessful!(standalone): AMS math features\@mathmargin=\skip44

Tags: amsmath, standalone

Conversion of `pdf` to `png` and whitespace elimination is completely applicable on my machine by following commands from command line:

`convert -density 300 labels.pdf -quality 90 labels.png
convert -trim labels.png file-trimmed.png`

Now, I'd like to do it automatically from compilation process within my editor (Tex Maker). Here is my approach to do it:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{C}_{\hat{x}}$

\end{document}
```

As I compiled my *.tex file with `LaTeX`, conversion failed and compiler throw a warning:

> Conversion failed! Please ensure that shell escape(standalone) is
>   enabled (e.g. use '-shell-escape').

So, I did add `-shell-escape` to `LaTeX` command:

`latex -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex`

The conversion failed again, this time with a new warning:

> Conversion unsuccessful!(standalone) There might be something wrong
>   with your(standalone) conversation software or the file permissions!)
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"Package:
>   amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features\@mathmargin=\skip43For
>   additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.

Then, I thought the issue might be resolved if I add the required option to `amsmath` as `\usepackage[?]{amsmath}`. But another warning just appeared, as following:

> Conversion unsuccessful!(standalone) There might be something wrong
>   with your(standalone) conversation software or the file permissions!)
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"Package:
>   amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math
>   features\@mathmargin=\skip44Documentation for the amsmath package is
>   found in amsldoc.dvi(or .pdf or .tex).

And I'm stuck on the problem at this point...

***could you give my some advice about it?!***

**Update 1**: `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex` leads to following warning (with no generated `png`):

> Conversion unsuccessful!(standalone) There might be something wrong
>   with your(standalone) conversation software or the file permissions!)
>   ) Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:693 strings out of
>   49392110613 string characters out of 314727358258 words of memory out
>   of 30000004047  multiletter control sequences out of 15000+2000003640
>   words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000841
>   hyphenation exceptions out of  819134i,1n,56p,169b,48s stack positions
>   out of 5000i,500n, 10000p,200000b,50000sNo pages of output.

**Update 2**: `pdflatex --shell-escape %.tex` leads to the error reflecting in **Update 1**. And here is the log file:

```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded
> format=pdflatex 2016.5.13)  17 JAN 2017 21:41 entering extended mode
> **labels.tex (C:\MyTEMP\labels.tex LaTeX2e <2011/06/27> Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
> abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan,
> coptic,  croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi,
> finnish, french, ga lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek,
> gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland ic, indonesian, interlingua,
> irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,  lithuanian,
> malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
> german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish,
> portuguese, roman ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian,
> spanish, swedish, swissgerm an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen,
> ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl ishmax, welsh, loaded.
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\standalone\standalone.cls"
> Document Class: standalone 2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX
> sub-files stand alone ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty" Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO) Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX
> not detected. ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty" Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO) Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode
> is detected. ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty" Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty" Package: xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
> 
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
> \XKV@toks=\toks14 \XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15 \XKV@depth=\count79 File:
> xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
> 
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex")))
> \sa@internal=\count80 \c@sapage=\count81
> 
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\standalone\standalone.cfg"
> File: standalone.cfg 2015/07/15 v1.2 Default configuration file for
> 'standalone ' class ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls" Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo" File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) \c@part=\count82
> \c@section=\count83 \c@subsection=\count84 \c@subsubsection=\count85
> \c@paragraph=\count86 \c@subparagraph=\count87 \c@figure=\count88
> \c@table=\count89 \abovecaptionskip=\skip41 \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
> \bibindent=\dimen102 ) \sa@box=\box26 runsystem(pdflatex 
> -shell-escape  -jobname "labels" "\expandafter\def\csname s a@internal@run\endcsname{1}\input{labels}")...executed.
> 
> 
> (C:\MyTEMP\labels.aux) runsystem(imgconvert -density 300 labels.pdf 
> -quality 90 labels.png)...execute d.
> 
> 
> 
> Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful! (standalone)       
> There might be something wrong with your (standalone)             
> conversation software or the file permissions!
> 
>  ) )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  691 strings out of
> 493921  10597 string characters out of 3147273  58409 words of memory
> out of 3000000  4047 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
> 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000  841
> hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  34i,1n,56p,169b,51s stack
> positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
> 
> No pages of output. PDF statistics:  0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max.
> 8388607)  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)  1 words of
> extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
> 
> 
> \@envbody=\toks19 \multlinegap=\skip44 \multlinetaggap=\skip45
> \mathdisplay@stack=\toks20 LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line
> 2665. LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666. ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\jknappen\mathrsfs.sty" Package: mathrsfs
> 1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk) \symrsfs=\mathgroup4 )
> (C:\MyTEMP\labels.aux) LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
> OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
> line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input
> line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:
> Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:   
> ... okay on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
> OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
> line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on
> input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6. LaTeX Font
> Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6. LaTeX Font
> Info:    ... okay on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading
> font information for U+rsfs on input line 8.  ("C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\jknappen\ursfs.fd" File: ursfs.fd
> 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk) ) [1
> 
> {C:/Users/Matiking/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
> (C:\MyTEMP\labels.aux) )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used: 
> 1317 strings out of 493921  17907 string characters out of 3147273 
> 67358 words of memory out of 3000000  4643 multiletter control
> sequences out of 15000+200000  4589 words of font info for 19 fonts,
> out of 3000000 for 9000  841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191 
> 35i,4n,56p,279b,106s stack positions out of
> 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s <C:/Program Files/MiKTeX
> 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfont s/cm/cmmi7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7 .pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/hoekwater/rsfs/rsfs10.pfb> Output written on labels.pdf (1 page, 18693 bytes). PDF statistics:  18 PDF objects out
> of 1000 (max. 8388607)  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
> 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

**Update 3:**

Here is the `standalone.cfg` file's content:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesFile{standalone.cfg}[%
    2015/07/15
    v1.2
    Default configuration file for 'standalone' class]%
%% Enabled the "varwidth" option if the "varwidth" package is available:
%%\IfFileExists{varwidth.sty}{%
%%    \standaloneconfig{varwidth}%
%%}{}%

%% Default options:
\standaloneconfig{crop}

%% Option which 'preview' should be loaded with
\PassOptionsToPackage{active,tightpage}{preview}%

%% Enable 'preview' option by default:
%%\standaloneconfig{preview}

%% Remove the border:
\standaloneconfig{border=0pt}

%% Default preview border (used by standalone v0.x):
%%\standaloneconfig{border=0.50001bp}

%% Disable navigation symbols in beamer.
%% This must be done AtEndOfClass because the options are not processed yet,
%% so "beamer" mode is not enabled yet.
\AtEndOfClass{%
\ifstandalonebeamer
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%
\fi
}
%% vim: ft=tex
```

Comment: Works fine for me with `pdflatex --shell-escape`. Why are you using `latex`? Although I get a PNG with `latex`, it is definitely not the way to go here .... You would need to convert the DVI first as I doubt `convert` can manage DVI.

Comment: @cfr: Please find `Update 1`.

Comment: Don't use `interaction=nonstopmode` if you want to know what's happening. What's the point of `synctex` here? Beyond that, probably look in the log or see if `standalone` has a debug option.

Comment: @cfr: Those options were default, as I removed them but nothing gratifying occurred. Please check `Update 2`.

Comment: You said that you checked `convert` worked, but `standalone` is using `imgconvert`.

Comment: @cfr: Yes, as I said, `convert` does work from command prompt. How should I reset `standalone`'s reference from `imgconvert` to `convert`?

Comment: imgconvert is the name used in some windows applications of imgemagic to avoid a clash with the system convert command (which will reformat your disk) but your question is very hard to read as you have used quote `>` instead of code (four spaces) and line wrapped the error and log messages. it would be easier if you reposted them with teh original line endings in code sections.

Comment: You can change it. Just check the manual for `standalone`. It is `convert` by default on most systems, but not Windows for the reason @DavidCarlisle gave.

Comment: @cfr: I found another way, than editing `standalone.cfg`. I'd just copied `convert.exe` and remained the copy to `imgconvert.exe`. Now there's no error. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: @Roboticist You should look at the docs anyway, because the quality of the default conversion is probably awful. At least, it was for me. Definitely need higher DPI than I got by default.

Comment: @cfr: As I checked right now, the resolution of the generated png is 72. So, to increase it to 300 I should edit `standalone.cfg`, right?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't edit it. If you want to use a personalised one, you can. Or you can configure it in your document.

Comment: @cfr: Like this: `\documentclass[convert={density=300}]{standalone}`?

Comment: Probably. I don't use this myself. Why don't you try it?

Comment: @cfr: It didn't work. I just checked `standalone.cfg` and `standalone.cls`. In `standalone.cfg`, there is no default value corresponding to density or resolution (please find `Updade 3`). But in `standalone.cls`, there is a `\sa@convertvar{density}{300}`, whereas the resolution of generated images is 72.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation?

Comment: @cfr: That's exactly what I did before digging into those files... I'll continue... Thanks

Comment: `\documentclass[convert={density=1200}]{standalone}` gives bearable results for me. The default `300` is horrible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op found a workable solution and noted it in a comment.